# Material-UI MenuItems didnt show after selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui and when selected the menuitems, it didn't show up but it changes the state. here's my code

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            amount: "",
        }

// Change amount of picture
        onAmountChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({ [event.target.name]: [event.target.value]})
        }

render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { amount  } = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
                <div>

                    <FormControl>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="amount-pic">Amount</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            value={amount}
                            onChange={this.onAmountChange}
                            name= 'amount'

                        >   
                            <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={15}>15</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={30}>30</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </div>


        );  
    }
```

there's no error showing and it worked to change the state amount, the number just didnt show when i selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is your function `onAmountChange`: the value is `event.target.value`, not `[event.target.value]`. Because `[event.target.value]` is an array

```
onAmountChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
```